# Adding A Mesh Collider Async

Tags: unity, collision-detection, procedural-generation

I am building an infinite landscape and I generate all of the terrains procedurally. I recently offloaded my terrain generation code onto another thread to try to eliminate the freeze up when new chunks are loaded, but I've found that:

A) Unity objects and functions cannot be accessed by other threads
B) The slowdown I am seeing is not because of my generation code, but because of adding a mesh collider. If I take away the collider, it runs completely smooth.

My question is is it possible to add a mesh collider async or at the very least use the already calculated mesh values or simplify the collider or optimize it somehow? The frame drops take it from over 220 FPS down to 40 FPS so it's pretty intensive. I wish I could use primitive colliders but the terrain shape is fairly complex and the player has to walk on it.

Comment: Have you tried chopping your physics chunks into smaller pieces, to simplify the amount of work you need to do to load the next chunk?

Comment: Have you considered adding the collider when the player is close enough to reach that area?

Comment: DMGregory yes I was thinking about that, but if it drops a lot of frames when I load the whole chunk then wouldn't it just drop a few frames many times as I load each piece?

Comment: Tomer Shahar that's what I am doing now, only loading the chunk once the player is walking towards it.